# Substring function to keep start and end while hide center

Tags: javascript

I am looking to get this

```
Abcd...LMNO
```

from this

```
AbcdefghijkLMNO
```

Mean i am looking to keep first 4 and last 4 while show 3 dots to hide center part. How to do this properly in JS using substring or some better function.

Comment: Have you tried to code this at all?

Comment: what about shorter strings? please add some more use cases.

Comment: `"AbcdefghijkLMNO".replace(/(.{4}).*(.{4})/, "$1...$2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "AbcdefghijkLMNO";
var restr = str.slice(0,4)+"..."+str.slice(-4);
console.log(restr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the first four and  last four characters and join them with dots.

```js
const getShort = s => (s.match(/^.{1,4}|.{1,4}$/g) || [s]).join('...');

console.log(getShort('AbcdefghijkLMNO'));
console.log(getShort('AbcdefghijkLMN'));
console.log(getShort('AbcdefghijkLM'));
console.log(getShort('AbcdefghijkL'));
console.log(getShort('Abcdefghijk'));
console.log(getShort('Abcdefghij'));
console.log(getShort('Abcdefghi'));
console.log(getShort('Abcdefgh'));
console.log(getShort('Abcdefg'));
console.log(getShort('Abcdef'));
console.log(getShort('Abcde'));
console.log(getShort('Abcd'));
console.log(getShort('Abc'));
console.log(getShort('Ab'));
console.log(getShort('A'));
console.log(getShort(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to do, just use correctly the [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method and then return everything concatenated.

here you have a working example and a dynamic selector for the length of the start and end of the function.

```js
const abbrev = (str = "", amount = 0) => {
  if (amount * 2 > str.length) return str;
  const start = str.substring(0, amount);
  const end = str.substring(str.length - amount);
  return `${start}...${end}`
}

const result = abbrev("abcdefghijklmn", 3);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "AbcdefghijkLMNO";
var pre = str.substring(0,4);
var post = str.substring(str.length-4,str.length);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pre+'...'+post;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Try this and tell me.